# centos httpd.conf set different ip for a directory

Tags: centos, directory, apache-httpd, ip

I have 3 IPs in my server, I want use them to increase twitter API limits.

How to set a different ip for a directory in centos 6.1 `httpd.conf` (Apache 2.3.1)

I added these line in the bottom of `httpd.conf`

```
<VirtualHost NEW IP:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com/subdir
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com/subdir
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/subdir
    <directory "/var/www/html/subdir">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I test `/var/www/html/subdir/index.php` with code

```
<?php
function get_server_ip() {
    if (isset($_SERVER)) {
        if($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']) {
            $server_ip = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
        }else{
            $server_ip = $_SERVER['LOCAL_ADDR'];
        }
    }else {
        $server_ip = getenv('SERVER_ADDR');
    }
    return $server_ip;
}
echo get_server_ip();
?>
```

it still return OLD IP (default ip for my server). So is it possible and how? If it couldn't, how to use 3 IPs to increase twitter API limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing an apache configurations is not enough. To make it work you have to configure multiple IP Address into your Centos (RedHat) box.

Assuming that you have only one phisical network interface `eth0`, then you have this file that contain all the relevant parameters :

```
$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=static
BROADCAST=192.168.0.255
IPADDR=192.168.1.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NETWORK=192.168.1.0
ONBOOT=yes
```

(This is a sample statical ip configuration for IP=192.168.1.1, yours may and will vary)

All this is explained here:  [CENTOS-Network Configuration Files](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-files.html) and [CENTOS-Interface Configuration Files](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html)

To assign another IP to the same phisical network interface `eth0` do this (as `root`) :

```
$ cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/
$ cp ifcfg-eth0 ifcfg-eth0:1
$ vi ifcfg-eth0:1
```

and then change IPADDR to the new file (and check/change all the other parameters)

You can do the same for third new IP doing `cp ifcfg-eth0 ifcfg-eth0:2` and edit the file.

Then you have to restar network to apply changes (stop apache before):

```
$ service network restart
```

Check the new config :

```
$ ifconfig
```

You will see listed the interface configuration for `eth1` , `eth1:1` , `eth1:2`  (and probabily more iterfaces like `lo` -> loopback )